# Xcode, Swift, can't seem to add a target to a UIButton

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to get this code to print some text when the button is pressed in the iPhone 6 simulator. However, I don't get any results in the console and I tried to call the function from within the initialisation - which returned to the console - so I don't know what's wrong. Also, there are other buttons in the ViewController that seem to be working just fine. Thanks for your help.

```
import UIKit

class RatingControl: UIView {

    // MARK: Initialisation

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // simple button to test
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)


        addSubview(button)
    }

    // MARK: Button Action

    func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        print("Button pressed ")

    }
```

}

Comment: Your code works perfectly in the viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear. Why don't you just put it there?

Comment: sorry i'm not quite sure what you mean, could you clarify. Where should I put the code, it's already in it's own swift file RatingControl.swift

Comment: also i'm following the apple tutorials and it's trying to show you how to implement a custom control

Comment: I'm just curious if you could replace " required init?(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {super.init(coder: aDecoder)" with "override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad"